# Allow cursor selection anywhere in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a single `UITextView`, which lets you write multiple lines of text.

How can I let users select letters in between words without a long press?

Currently, when using the touchscreen to select characters between a word, the cursor either goes the start or end of the word:

**Example: clicking on 'c' moves cursor to end of word**

[image: cursor at end]

**Example: clicking on 'a' moves cursor to start of word**

[image: cursor at start]

**Desired cursor behavior: Selection anywhere in text**
[image]

The feature of allowing text selection anywhere (without the long press + magnifying glass) is found in many code editor apps for iOS, such as [Coda](https://panic.com/coda-ios/) and [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/).

Comment: Isn't this more of a hardware issue? Or at least a system issue. After all, on an iPad there's a way to "slide" the insertion point to wherever you want it. But on on the iPhone. So this isn't really up to you.

Comment: @matt I just tried some code editor apps for the iPhone, some of them allow an insertion point at any point but I'm not sure how they achieved this. For example in one of the apps, with this text `System.out.println("hello")`, the user can select anywhere in the `UITextView` to change the argument.

Comment: character level selection editors (Coda and Pythonista ?) might not use UITextView. You could build a custom text editor view (consult "Text Programming Guide for iOS" document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a difficult challenge to achieve.

I will preface that the issue with this approach is consistency. Remember that your users are using their fingers, rather than stilii. A finger has a large surface area, and hitting a precise pixel zone is quite difficult, especially with small text. I would suggesting playing not in the simulator, where you have a precise pointing device, but on a device.

The first challenge is to disable the default tap behavior or `UITextView`. This is not a difficult task - you can either "attack" the problem at the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` level, where you would have to understand what these touches are (single tap vs. pan vs. long press), or at the gesture recognizer level, where you'd disable the private gesture recognizers of the text view which specifically handle cursor movement in case of tap (vs the other touch types). I've done the latter for various projects, and it is possible. You could also try the approach without disabling the default behavior, but then the cursor may flicker. Test and decide.

Now to achieve what you need. Obtain the point of touch somehow (either using `UIResponder` API or gesture recognizer). Remember, the text view is a scroll view which includes a large subview where the content is drawn into. You have to convert this touch point, from the text view coordinate system, to the internal view's coordinate system using the `convertPoint:` API. Once you have that, you can use the text view's layout manager to obtain the character index at the point of touch:

```
NSUInteger chIdx = [self characterIndexForPoint:touchPoint inTextContainer:self.textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
```

You can use this index to set the cursor of the text view using the `selectedRange` property.

Comment: Do you know how to add some leeway to the location used for `characterIndexForPoint`  e.g. registering taps plus/minus 1px as a tap on a character

Comment: You will have to do this heuristic yourself using `boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:`. Notice this is in glyph range space, while your cursor is in character range (`NSString` concept of character, anyway).

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that if the selection of a character is slightly over/above the line, `characterIndexForPoint` returns a bad index, corresponding to characters at the start/end of the line instead of the "closest" character in the y axis direction

I'm not sure how `boundingRectForGlyphRange` fits into my code. Is this the flow you mean: 1) get range of glyph for line of text in UITextView` 2) get bounding rect for glyph range 3) expand bounding rect by +/- 1 px 4) Use `characterIndexForPoint` to get index with bounding rect?

Comment: The only method I see that converts a point to any text range is the one I mentioned in the answer. So you need to use that first. Then, convert your character range to glyph range, and convert to rect. You can then do some heuristics (for instance, what you mention in the comment) on the point in conjunction with the rect - they are on the same coordinate system.

Comment: I see you have accepted the answer. Did you solve it? What did you do?

Comment: I accepted the answer for the logic, but I'm still working on solving it. I've also found an alternative, which is to use `WKWebView` which implements quite good character selection that seems to allow for some leeway compared to `UITextView`. Though, I'm still figuring out how to add the heuristics to `UITextView` as right now you need to be very precise or the cursor jumps to the end of a line before switching, as the `UITextView` is faster to load an editable area.

Comment: You might need to take the text view insets in account. Inspect the internal hierarchy of the text view to see how the views are layout. Also, there may be more margins to take into account. Text containers coordinate space may be different than the internal view, and you may need to adapt. Using web view is an interesting approach, but from experience, it is just not flexible enough. I have experience in rich text editor (mail HTML compose) and I used UIWeb & WKWeb, and you end up needing to swizzle a lot of the internals to get it to behave as you want. If you can confine to UIText, do it.

Comment: Yep, I've accounted for the text offsets. I can't get this method to work as the returned `glyphIndex` must be correct (i.e. not just the first or last character index) in order to create the `boundingRect` for needed to perform heuristics.

I also tried a another method with the `closestPosition` of the tap in the text view but unfortunately `rangeEnclosingPosition` returns nil when tapped slightly out of bounds

Here's a snippet of the methods

https://gist.github.com/timert/ab1bcc8463b6792753df637a80b394b4

Any other ideas?

Comment: Investigating. As for overriding the tap gesture - don't. I have discovered `closestPositionToPoint:` which does what you need. You return a position, and it puts the cursor there.

Comment: If you are interested in a down to metal approach, add a symbolic breakpoint to `__52-[UITextInputController _characterPositionForPoint:]_block_invoke` in a 64-bit simulator. This will give you Apple's algorithm for calculating their cursor position.

Comment: `closestPositionToPoint:` just [returns a position](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614523-closestpositiontopoint), not a rect. I used it in method 3 of the linked gist, so I can get a single position, but I'm not sure how to use it next since there isn't a bounding rect from it?

Comment: `closestPositionToPoint:` is used by the system to move the cursor when you tap. So if you implement that method to return the correct position you want, the system will move it there. It's just a matter of cracking the correct way to obtain it. Put a breakpoint in the method I suggested (`__52-[UITextInputController _characterPositionForPoint:]_block_invoke`) - you will see what the system does when a user taps.